# textview or something else

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to find the best approach to handle a user clicking a button, setting the text of that button to (in my attempt) a textview and then automatically move onto the the next textview to update on the next button press.
At the moment I can do this by manually specifying each element by ID to update but there must be a better way, or a different approach.

An example: imagine a table with 2 rows of each 4 columns (each contains a textview) and below that 6 buttons. When any button is pressed the first time the textview of the first column is set to the button text, the next press of any button sets the the textview of the second column is set to the button text, and so on. When a row is complete it will start back at column one of the next row.

at the moment I'm using a hard coded function triggered by the onclick event, I realized that I could implement some counter and user row[i]_col[j] (or such) but is there a better way to approach this (eg. some way similar to changing focus on edittext)?

```
    public void setValue(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_row1_col1);
    textView.setText(((Button) view).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your problem correctly ,

I would suggest using an array of Textviews instead of using findviewbyid so much (very pricey memory wise )

```
TextView [][] txtArr = new TextView[XSize][Ysize];
```

Initial that in the start once and use it in the on click later.

Comment: and on the buttonclick event just do the appropriate math to increment to the next text view?

Comment: yes , they would already be in order just change any text of them like you wanted